# .net Core 3 identity 'AccessFailedCount' not incrementing

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

I'm having a problem with a asp.net Core 3 identity project. I have created custom `UserStore` and `RoleStore` to use `Dapper` instead of `Entity Framework`. Most appears to be working, except upon a failed login attempt, the `AccessFailedCount` in the database is not being incremented. I have stepped through the code, and located where the logic is failing. It is in the `SignInManager` method named `CheckPasswordSignInAsync`, in this block:

```
if (UserManager.SupportsUserLockout && lockoutOnFailure)
{
    // If lockout is requested, increment access failed count which might lock out the user
    await UserManager.AccessFailedAsync(user);
    if (await UserManager.IsLockedOutAsync(user))
    {
        return await LockedOut(user);
    }
}
```

The value for `UserManager.SupportsUserLockout` is `false`, so it never hits the `AccessFailedAsync` method. But I'm not sure where this value comes from. The code block from `UserManager.SupportsUserLockout` in `UserManager` is:

```
public virtual bool SupportsUserLockout
{
  get
  {
    this.ThrowIfDisposed();
    return this.Store is IUserLockoutStore<TUser>;
  }
}
```

But I can't figure out what here sets it to false? Where does this value come from?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I got your problem, you haven't implemented `IUserLockoutStore<TUser>` interface. As you are not using the Entity framework so you need to implement all necessary stores your self. Below are the functions which you need to implement.

```
Task<int> GetAccessFailedCountAsync(TUser user, CancellationToken cancellationToken);
Task<bool> GetLockoutEnabledAsync(TUser user, CancellationToken cancellationToken);
Task<DateTimeOffset?> GetLockoutEndDateAsync(TUser user, CancellationToken cancellationToken);
Task<int> IncrementAccessFailedCountAsync(TUser user, CancellationToken cancellationToken);
Task ResetAccessFailedCountAsync(TUser user, CancellationToken cancellationToken);
Task SetLockoutEnabledAsync(TUser user, bool enabled, CancellationToken cancellationToken);
Task SetLockoutEndDateAsync(TUser user, DateTimeOffset? lockoutEnd, CancellationToken cancellationToken);
```

Once you implement `IUserLockoutStore<TUser>` interface you have to enable Lockout functionality for an individual user, in order to achieve that you just need to set `User.LockoutEnabled = 1 (true)` in `AspNetUsers` table.

I hope this will resolve your issue!